# Magento - Change css of New Account email's subject line

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I need to ask a very simple thing. Probably many of you might already know this. How to change the css of the subject line in the New Account transactional email.

So the subject line that is,

`Welcome {{var customer.firstname}}`

How can I make sure that the {{var customer.firstname}} is always first letter capital regardless of how the customer has actually inputted his/her name.

So even if its `john smith`,  the Subject lien should be `Welcome John`. The first letter being capital always.

How do i apply `text-transform:capitalize;` to {{var customer.firstname}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can do it with CSS.
So far only way I think you can do that is to apply the transformation on code level, in

`Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template::getProcessedTemplateSubject()`

by overloading this method and applying transformation say here:
`$processedResult = $processor->filter($this->getTemplateSubject());`
you'd probably replace `$this->getTemplateSubject()` with your own method.

EDIT: This will apply to all email templates, though, so if you wish it to apply only for specific template, use `$this->getTemplateId()` to make a filter. You can use `ucwords()` to capitalize first letter in PHP:

`$subject = "This is a subject line";

$capitalized = ucwords($subject); // produces "This Is A Subject Line"`

Comment: Thanks for your reply.`$this->getTemplateSubject()` is a generic method for all email's subject lines. I would just like to change the styling on 'New Account' email's subject line. And even in this method how do I actually make it to say that the subject line will always have `text-transform:capitalize;`

Comment: If you don't want to capitalize first letter in all email subjects, I'm sure that the class object containts template_id of some sort, try dumping the object or it's data with `var_dump()` and finding out what's in it. you can capitalize first character with `ucfirst()` in PHP.

Comment: `$this->getId()` will return template ID that you can use to create a filter only for specific templates (such as new account)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a go in a min...Can u edit your answer just to show that how can I use ucfirst() once I have got the email template i want. Also on second thoughts I dont really mind if each and every template's subject line is first letter capital. But how do i use ucfirst() on template Subject

Comment: I tried this `$processedResult = $processor->filter(ucwords($this->getTemplateSubject()));` but that just took away the firstname from the subject line completely. Any ideas what did i do wrong?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18109/discussion-between-ivn-and-netismine)

Comment: try  
`$processedResult = ucwords($processor->filter($this->getTemplateSubject()));`

Comment: Probably just a good idea for you to add this `$processedResult` line  in ur edited answer for others to see. Just a suggestion.